# nHibernate Disjunction not expected behaviour

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate

I'm trying to make a disjunction of two Criterias, but the result is not the expected.
I'm trying to get all the books of one person (in his personal library or in the libraries of his teams).

1st Criteria: // returns 1

```
myBooks = session.CreateCriteria<Book>()
                .CreateCriteria("Library")
                .CreateAlias("Users", "usr")
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("usr.Id", myUserId))
                .List().Count;
```

2nd Criteria // returns 1

```
myTeamsBooks = session.CreateCriteria<Book>()
                .CreateCriteria("Library")
                .CreateAlias("Teams", "grp")         
                .Add(Restrictions.In("grp.Id", myTeamsIds))
                .List().Count;
```

Disjunction // Expected 2, returns 0!!

```
allMyBooks = session.CreateCriteria<Book>()
                .CreateCriteria("Library")
                .CreateAlias("Users", "usr")
                .CreateAlias("Teams", "grp")
                .Add(Restrictions.Disjunction()
                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("usr.Id", myUserId))
                    .Add(Restrictions.In("grp.Id", myTeamsIds))
                )
                .List().Count;
```

What I'm doing wrong in the disjunction?
I've try as well with `.Add(Restrictions.Or(` with the same result.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in this case would be related to the **JOIN** type. We would need `LEFT` one, but the default *(not specified)* is `INNER`. So, adjust the `CreatAlias` like this, and correct results should be returned:

```
.CreateAlias("Users", "usr", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
.CreateAlias("Teams", "grp", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! 
Trying to find it in the documentation I've seen that is not in the main documentation reference, but is there! http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#createAlias(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)